# How to access the skill tree in Assassin's Creed Unity on PS4?

Tags: assassins-creed-unity

As the title says, how to access the skill tree in Assassin's Creed Unity on PS4?

I cannot find any options anywhere in the menu. I looked at videos on Youtube and the IGN Wiki, but videos there show a different main menu than I get on my PS4.

This video for example
http://www.ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-5-unity/Major_Changes_and_Differences
shows the main menu with items:

- Progress Tracker
- Character Customization
- Play Together
- My Brotherhood
- Estore
- etc.

[image]

But on my PS4, the main menu only has:

- Progress Tracker
- EStore
- Database
- UPlay
- Options

[image]

**So, it seems that I do not have the menu item "Character Customization" under which the skill tree would usually be.**

I just recently bought AC Unity from the PSN Store (it's the latest up to date version) after I finished AC Syndicate, where I didn't have such problem.

Update: I just completed memory sequence 1. Does the skill tree maybe just come up later in the game? That's the only idea I might have here.
Just getting this assumption from the posts in https://steamcommunity.com/app/289650/discussions/0/624074858717831438/

Comment: Why the downvote? UI-wise this is not the best design decision imho, and it's not stated anywhere that the skill tree will appear at a later stage in the menu. At least not very common from other Ubisoft open-word games.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you surmised, you need to play through the story some more to unlock that feature. If I remember correctly, you will unlock the skill tree and equipment customization after you finish sequence 2. This is supported by the fact that the Skills list in the same guide (http://www.ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-5-unity/Assassin_Skills) has "Complete Sequence 2" as the unlock requirement for most of the skills.

Comment: Indeed, got the skill tree now that I finished 2-2. Weird though that they don't simply put the menu item there, maybe disabled with a note.